# Sharing lua globals across script files?

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

Say I have a script like

```
my_global = my_cpp_class()
my_global = nil
```

now while this properly calls the destructor of my_cpp_class, this code does not:

```
my_global = my_cpp_class()
call_script("a.lua") -- a.lua contains "my_global = nil"
-- "call_script" is actually a simplified notation 
-- I create script as userdata and then I can 
-- set its child scripts that should be reloaded once script is modified
```

The same when I simply replace call_script with dofile.

Basically, I want a particular script file to be able to assign "nil" to an existing global so the old value becomes *unreachable*.

Now what I need this for is script reloading in real time - whenever a script file is modified it is instantly compiled and called with `call_script` again with its child scripts in runtime, so it should cause globals to be reassigned and hence old values should be garbage collected.

Is there easier, more preferred way to do such script reloads?

Should I use locals somehow, or manipulate with environments?
I use luabind, if it's relevant.

Comment: Consider sandboxing your scripts within their own _ENV, this way you can just give the reloaded scripts a fresh environment instead of cleaning up the old/common one (and probably missing something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute the script within the same `lua_State`, the global actually *is* reassigned (you can check that the variable is visible before assigning `nil`). The C++ object's destructor is run when the object is collected, which may not happen immediately after it becomes unreachable. Calling [`lua_gc()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_gc) from C++ or [`collectgarbage()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage) from Lua will probably help.